# Show that the normalizer of a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $A_5$ has order $10$, and is a maximal subgroup of $A_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

The problem is stated as follows:

> Show that the normalizer of a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $A_5$ has order $10$, and is a maximal subgroup of $A_5$.

Here is my attempt:

$\textit{Solution:}$  By Sylow's theorem, we know that $Syl_5(A_5) \neq \emptyset$. Furthermore, $n_5(A_5)\mid |A_5| = 2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 5$, but the additional condition that $n_5(A_5) \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ narrows down the possibility to $n_5(A_5) \in \{1, 6\}$. However, if $n_5(A_5) = 1$, then $Syl_5(A_5) = \{Q\}$ where $Q \unlhd A_5$. But this is a nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $A_5$, contradicting that $A_5$ is simple. It must then be that $n_5(A_5) = 6$. Sylow's theorem further guaruntees that $|A_5 : N_{A_5}(Q)| = n_5(A_5) = 6$, so that $$|N_{A_5}(Q)| = \frac{|A_5|}{6} = \frac{2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2\cdot 3} = 2 \cdot 5 = 10$$ which completes the first part of the problem.

Now, suppose $M \leq A_5$ such that $N_{A_5}(Q) < M$. It remains to show that $M = A_5$. By Lagrange's theorem, $2 \cdot 5 = |N_{A_5}(Q)|$ divides $ |M|$, and $|M|$ divides $|A_5| = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. Thus it must be that $|M| \in \{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5, 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5, 2^2\cdot 5\}$. If $|M| = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, then it has index $2$ in $A_5$, so that it is normal, again contradicting simplicity of $A_5$. The problem is done if we can show that $|M| \neq 2^2 \cdot 5$, but I don't know where to go from here. I see that by order considerations, $Q \in Syl_5(M)$. By Sylow's theorem, $n_5(M) | 2^2$, yet $n_5(M) \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ so it must be that $n_5(M) = 1$. It follows that $Syl_5(M) = \{Q\}$, and that $Q \unlhd M$. Therefore, $M= N_M(Q) = N_{A_5}(Q) \cap M$. This implies that $M \leq N_{A_5}(Q)$, so $20 = |M| \leq |N_{A_5}(Q)| = 10$, which is absurd. It must then be that $|M| = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = |A_5|$ so that $M = A_5$ and $N_{A_5}(Q)$ is maximal.

Is this correct? Something about my last argument seems a little funny to me, particularly by arguing by way of a Sylow subgroup of a subgroup of $A_5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Another way to see this is that if $|M|=2^2\cdot 5$, $M$ has index $3$ in $A_5$, thus we get a non-trivial homomorphism $A_5 \to S_3$ by the action of $A_5$ on the coset space $A_5/M$, the kernel of which is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ which is impossible as $A_5$ is simple.